# How should I really remove UIAlertview from view - Text run over the previous text bug

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, uialertview

Hello everyone I got weired bug which I can't solve - I dig over the internet and couldn't find any solution.
I got a viewcontroller screen with 6 buttons on it. I want to show the user a UIAlertview with a description text any time when clicks on one of those buttons.
The problem is that in the first button I got the text right but the problem begins from the second button and so on.
The new UIAlertview shows the new description text together with the old text so the new text can't be read.

From the debuger I found that the old UIAlertview are there but just not shown on the main screen.

What is the right way to remove it from the view controller?

This is my dismiss function:

```
 @objc func dismissAlert() {
    guard let targetView = mytargetView else {
        return
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {self.alertView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: targetView.frame.size.height, width: targetView.frame.size.width-80, height: 300)}, completion: {done in
        if done {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { done in
                if done {
                    self.alertView.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

[image: The previous UIAlerts are still in the background]

Comment: Alert views are just that - something you present modally and dismiss. This doesn't seem like what you are trying to do. So maybe start simple. Present one - and I mean `present` - and dismiss it by using `dismiss. Then try a second step, whatever that is. My guess is that you want something **very** different than an alert that is eight(?) views deep.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. My view is just a basic view with six buttons which the UIAlert goal is just to pop up some info about each button and what it does. But every time I press dismiss and lunch a new UIAlert than the new info come out together with the old info just behind it so it is a text over text and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The `dismissAlert` method is not the proper way to dismiss an alert view. You can simply call the `dismiss` method on any alert view to properly dismiss it.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .alert)

// Presenting an alert
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Dismissing an alert
alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Dear Malik,
Thank you for your answer.
I tried your code but xcode doesn't accept it.

after declaring "let alert" xcode doesn't know the code for dismissing 
alert.dismiss() nor present()
it gives for both the error:
"Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration"

I tried to figure out other solutions but nothing til far.
Do you have any other suggestions?

Best Regards,
Ido

Comment: @Ido The answer I provided should be adjusted as per your needs and not used as is. It sounds like that you might be trying to access the alert outside of the scope that it's created in. Can you please share the exact piece of code that you tried?